# Match multiple lines one after another

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a log file which among other data contains the below pair:

```
[Connectivity]  07.07 11:35:08
[REGISTERED]
```

Therefore I want to find each such pair of lines and print only the date and time.
My example txt file would be:

```
[Connectivity]  07.07 11:35:08
[REGISTERED]

#other stuff in the log#

[Connectivity]  07.07 17:20:22
[REGISTERED]

#more stuff in the log#

[Connectivity]  07.07 19:10:29
[REGISTERED]
```

What I want to print should look like

```
1: 07.07 11:35:08
2: 07.07 17:20:22
3: 07.07 19:10:29
```

Of course each time the dates and time would be different when using log file from another day. I assume i should use RE to accomplish this but I cannot make my code look for the two combined lines, only one.

I tired a crude regex but it failed me:

```
re.findall('(\\[Connectivity\\])(\s)(\d\d\\.\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s\\[REGISTERED\\]', line, re.MULTILINE)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Try [`\[Connectivity]\s*(\d{2}\.\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+\[REGISTERED]`](https://regex101.com/r/2zbNpj/1) with the `re.findall` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\[Connectivity\]\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+\[REGISTERED]', line, re.MULTILINE)
['07.07 11:35:08', '07.07 17:20:22', '07.07 19:10:29']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('log.txt')]
final_results = [re.sub("\[Connectivity\]\s", '', data[i]) for i in range(len(data)-1) if i.startswith("[Connectivity]") and data[i+1] == "[REGISTERED]"]
 new_final_data = ["{}: {}".format(i+1, a) for i, a in enumerate(final_results)]
```